# Central + local cache with PHP

Tags: php, memcached, apc

I have a multi server setup where all servers run the same code and need to share the same cache. The amount of cached data is huge and is in a separate memcached server.

This does work but the memcached server is slow. Slow meaning it takes about 0.3 ms in the best case. This sounds like fast but APC is a lot faster and in my experience more reliable.

Building a cache that locally stores only data it needed, reads from APC first and has fallback to memcached is trivial. The hard problem is deleting keys and clearing the cache. I have thought about creating a daemon in each node and broadcasting the delete and clear commands to all of them but this gets very complicated very fast. Especially since APC is not shared between CLI and FPM. So my question is has this problem been solved already?

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar setup. But our case is more of read only data. But occasionally we flush the data in 2 levels of caches.

We had a script to flush the selected keys in 2 levels of cache @ once. We deleted the keys in memcache and then in all the apc caches of cluster(write through approach). Since our case is more of caching read only data - it is working well.

May be you want to try this!

The flush has 2 components:

1. Doing the delete in memcache (memcache delete api call)
2. A php component for deleting a given key from APC cache.

Since the php component exists in all nodes of our server cluster and we know the list of servers @ any given instance. We trigger set of curl calls of the APC delete component.

Comment: In general, yes. Can you share the technical details of how that flush is done exactly? Is it done manually or is there a script for it? If there is, what does it look like? How would you run the script? How to scale the script to X number of servers?